# Is it haram to do freelance work using our company name

Tags: practical-islam, work

Iam a software developer, currently our company is closed and we have no work.now I got a freelance work from my colleague and he used our company name to get this project.is it haram? please help me.

Comment: if you mean using your company name as reference for your work/partners/experience then what should be wrong in doing so? Else please elaborate!